# List of strings into sublist of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I got this, but how do I go from this:

```
['99', '88', '77', '66\n', '11', '22', '33', '44\n', '78', '58', '68', '88\n']
```

to:

```
[[99, 88, 77, 66], [11, 22, 33, 44], [78, 58, 68, 88]]
```

This is the function i used to get the first output:

```
def class_avg(open_file):
    new = []
    number = []

    for i in open_file:
        student = i.split(',')
        for grade in student[4:]:
            new.append(grade)
    return new
```

This is the file format:

```
Smith, Joe,9911991199,smithjoe9,99,88,77,66
Ash, Wood,9912334456,ashwood,11,22,33,44
Full, Kare,9913243567,fullkare,78,58,68,88
```

Comment: How did you get that first line, I bet we can fix your original file read so you don't have this issue in the first place

Comment: I am smelling an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem here. Maybe you might want to show us your code.

Comment: yes, it's much easier to fix the output. create a new list in the loop, and strip the line, convert to integer, you're done

Comment: `student = i.strip().split(',')` would give you the items with the trailing new line character cleared.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunk, apply this, then you can iterate over it using `str.strip` for removing newlines and `map` for applying ints, or just do `int(s.strip())`

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you should be reading processing your file to avoid the problem in the first place:

```
def class_avg(open_file):
    new = []    
    for line in open_file:
        student = line.strip().split(',')
        new.append(list(map(int, student[4:])))
    return new
```

As @Jean-FrançoisFabre notes, `.strip` isn't really necessary if you're going to convert to `int` since it deals with whitespace. You could really just do something like:

```
return [[int(s) for s in line.split()[4:]] for line in open_file]
```

Or better yet, use the csv module:

```
import csv
with open('path_to_my_file.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [[int(x) for x in row[4:]] for row in reader]
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yep. fixed

Comment: when converting to int, you don't even need to strip. And in that case, the csv module always comes to mind.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, I would probably use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
output = []
sub_l = []
for i in your_input:
    if "\n" in i:
        sub_l.append(int(i.replace("\n","")))
        output.append(sub_l)
        sub_l=[]
    else:
        sub_l.append(int(i))

print(output)
```

Comment: This is nearly identical to the answer posted by Van Peer. Additionally, `int()` will strip whitespace, so the `replace()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you like iteration tricks...

```
>>> l = ['99', '88', '77', '66\n', '11', '22', '33', '44\n', '78', '58', '68', '88\n']
>>> [[int(x) for x in sub] for sub in zip(*[iter(l)]*4)]
[[99, 88, 77, 66], [11, 22, 33, 44], [78, 58, 68, 88]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=['99', '88', '77', '66\n', '11', '22', '33', '44\n', '78', '58', '68', '88\n']

y=[]
z=[]

for x in l:
    y.append(int(x))
    if '\n' in x:
        z.append(y)
        y=[]

print (z)
```

Output

```
[[99, 88, 77, 66], [11, 22, 33, 44], [78, 58, 68, 88]]
```

Comment: Checkin against `'\n' not in x` is very inefficient as it causes the entire program to run `0(n^2)`.

Comment: And in the `else` clause you do the replace which is way worse.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever What's `0(n^2)`? And I think you confuse `x` and `l`...

Comment: @StefanPochmann It is called [Big Oh notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). You do string search which costs `0(n)` and you do that for each `x` so it is `0(n^2)`.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever Not sure what your "n" is, please clarify. And please stop using `0` instead of `O`.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever actually, it would be `O(m*n)` where `m` is the length of the strings and `n` is the number of strings. Since we don't actually expect `m` to increase, we can effectively say this `m` is constant, and the actual problem is `O(n)`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or you could just say O(|inputfile|), and since that's optimal, there's really nothing to complain about...

Answer (score 0):

Try this function: You can change stepper if you want to change the length, of the sub list.

```
def list_divider(ls,stepper=4):
    #Get rid of the \n.
    ls=list(map(str.strip,ls))
    result=[]
    pos = 0
    #Slice the list  by moving pos 4 steps each time
    while pos<=len(ls)-1:
        result.append(ls[pos:pos+stepper])
        pos+=stepper
    return result
```

I hope that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly concise way to do it that uses the `csv` module to read the file and the `itertools` module to reformat the data for processing calcultions.

```
import csv
import itertools

def class_avg(open_file):
    grades = tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(  # Put all grades into single sequence.
                    itertools.chain(map(int, row[4:])  # Convert grades in row to integers.
                        for row in csv.reader(open_file))))
    total = sum(grades)
    return total / len(grades)

with open('class_grades.txt', newline='') as file:
    print(class_avg(file))  # -> 61.0
```

The value printed is for the values in the sample file in your question.